# Build displays black screen with static

Tags: unity, android

Something really odd happens when I'm trying to load a scene.

[image: Odd black-static screen]

It is supposed to look like this (it also has to show the next scene after loading):

[image: A black screen with "Think about the Universe to continue. Thinking progress:" and a loading bar]

What is going on?

Comment: Oh my God. After 6 hours I've found where was an error. I marked Split Application Binary.

Comment: In the future for your questions try to do the following: Tell us exactly what you're expecting, tell us what you think the problem is, tell us what you've done to try to solve it. From your question here, it's not clear to me what problem you're trying to solve. I don't know how your game is supposed to look, so I see nothing wrong with your screenshot.

Comment: @Byte56 ok, next time I'll make the question bigger :) I'll edit the post so you can see how it is supposed to look like

Comment: @Gnemlock yes. So shoud I delete unrelated  tags and edit the question when it is solved in situation like this?

Comment: @Sharpy, primarily, you should be ensuring your question is clear, and shows research effort. In cases where you figure it out, you should post the solution as an answer. This makes your question useful, if other users stumble upon it with the same question. Given the solution, we can see that it may have been rather difficult or impossible to diagnose your problem based off what you actually provided. I have edited your question to include "I split application binary", and posted a "why that happened" answer. I feel this makes the question more useful, going forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You confirm to have selected ["Split Binary Application"](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/android-OBBsupport.html) from the publisher settings. Used incorrectly, this can have disastrous affect on your game. Unless you specifically intend to use this feature, turn it off.

---

This feature allows you to split your android application into multiple files, primarily for the purpose of publishing a game to the Google Play Store that would normally exceed the size limitations of 100MB. While you still end up with an `.apk` file, you build a lot of your required files into additional `.obb` files, including any *additional* scene (the first scene will still be packaged in the `.apk`) and any resources.

---

Using this feature, your application will still *look* for the additional data files, but if it can not find them it will continue on *as is*. It seems this is the case, here. The first scene looks unable to correctly display its game objects, likely due to the loss of your resource files. This also explains why you can not move to other scenes, as without the additional data files, you do not have access to your other scenes.

---

Going forward, you can still choose to "Split Binary Application". Just make sure that you *also* copy the required `.obb` files across with your `.apk`. You should place these files *together*, on your phone. Alternatively, you can set the path to your `.obb` files from the first scene, either from local access or after downloading them from an external source. You can read more about the ["Split Binary Application" feature at the official Unity documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/android-OBBsupport.html).